# struct.error: 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My code below throws the following error

```
struct.error: 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767
```

I managed to connect to the Cloud SQL postgres DB and read/write my dataframes to the database. However, I am experiencing the following error no matter what I do.

struct.error: 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767

This error doesnt happen when the dataframes are small, compact and columns do not have too many NaN values in them. However, when there are many NaN values in the columns, the program throws the following error.

Separately I have tried using df = df.fillna(0) to fill the NaN values with 0. But it did not work as well, and the same error surfaced.

It completely fails on GCP Cloud SQL. However, it works perfectly on Heroku PostgreSQL managed services database. There must be something wrong with Cloud SQL.

Any assistance would be much appreciated

```
from google.cloud.sql.connector import connector
import sqlalchemy
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"GSheet-Credentials-LL-tech2.json")


# build connection for db using Python Connector
def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
        os.environ['LL_DB_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME'],
        "pg8000",
        user=os.environ['LL_DB_USER'],
        password=os.environ['LL_DB_PASSWORD'],
        db=os.environ['LL_DB_NAME'],
    )
    return conn


# create connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://", creator=getconn)

def db_connect():
    with pool.connect() as conn:
        current_time = conn.execute(
            "SELECT NOW()").fetchone()
        print(f"Time: {str(current_time[0])}")
db_connect()
```

Comment: can you update the code to show the dataframe logic and how you are trying to insert it into Cloud SQL? Will be very beneficial for debugging.Thanks!

Comment: Hey @yj_n could you share your solution as an answer? Other users with similar issues can use it as part of their troubleshooting path

Comment: Hey @JackWotherspoon -- i just tested it again. It failed to work again. Appreciate if you could help. Thank you

Comment: Hey @yj_n can you update the code with the dataframe logic you are using? I need to try and tell if the issue is with the dataframe logic of the Python Connector library itself. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JackWotherspoon - Many thanks for getting back. And apologies for the late response. I have saved the dataframe out into a csv file. You can download the csv file from the link below, and read it into a dataframe using .read_csv()

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bVarENcdSH4wpVink5kROZXhLiVEPSdr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's highly likely you are trying to insert more values than 32767. If your CSV file shape is such as `n_rows x n_cols > 32767`, that will trigger this error.